# call c# function from javascript onclick event button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how to use something like this :

```
<script>
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: 
'<div><input type="text" id="txt_newpl" value="place name"/>' +
'</br> <input type="button" id="btn_newpl" value="submit" onclick="btn_newpl_Click" /></div>'
         });</script>
```

and c# code is like this

```
    protected void btn_newpl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{...}
```

how can call this c# function from javascript event click

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a code behinds button click event using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156327/how-to-call-a-code-behinds-button-click-event-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger button event, you have to add this line of code in javascript.

```
document.getElementById("btn_newpl").click();
```

Your button must have `runat="server"` and `OnServerClick="btn_newpl_Click"` attributes.

If your problem is that the `input` element is in **javascript string**, than you can [extract the string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750815/get-the-string-representation-of-a-dom-node) of `input` and concatenate to your string on **client side**.

```
<input type="button" id="btn_newpl" value="submit" 
       OnServerClick="btn_newpl_Click"
       runat="server" />

<script>
var tmp = document.createElement("div");
tmp.appendChild(document.getElementById('btn_newpl'));

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: 
       '<div><input type="text" id="txt_newpl" value="place name"/>' +
       '</br>'+tmp.innerHTML+'</div>'
    })
});
</script>
```

Please note that you **don't** actually **call a C# function**, you just trigger the click event on webforms and a **postback to sever** will be done. The server will figure out which event has been triggered and will execute the C# function.

Source: [How to call a code behinds button click event using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156327/how-to-call-a-code-behinds-button-click-event-using-javascript)

Comment: btn_newpl just defined in javascript , i dont have access this button in html and i can't do this !

Comment: @aliiii your button don't have 1 important attribute runat="server" an the OnClick event must be changed in OnServerClick

Comment: when i use OnServerClick="btn_newpl_Click" and runat="server" together map not loading !! Note that my button is in script tag not in html

Comment: @aliiii try to add input element on page and get it with javascript, as an workaround on this, see my updated answer.

Comment: @aliiii please fell free to edit my answer, if you think changes that you made can improve it :)

Comment: Most of the changes was in C # :-) Anyway, i changed this answer a little

Comment: can i use this method to create textbox ?

Comment: Yes, you can use this method for almost all controls (or even all :D)

Comment: to create textbox , i use this codes !            

html code :
<input type="text" id="txt_newpl" value="placeName" runat="server" />
and javascript code :
var txt_java = document.createElement("input");            txt_java.appendChild(document.getElementById('txt_newpl'));
 
how to access value of this textbox ?
txt_java.value not working

Comment: @aliiii You are doing it wrong, but this is another question. Also you should consider to rename this question.

Comment: ok :-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792246/get-value-of-dom-element-in-code-behind
Can you help me?