# How to exchange value between an input and and asp:textbox controler

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how to use something like this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_place_name" CssClass="form-control ltr"  ValidationGroup="add" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <input type="text" id="txt_newpl" value="placeName" runat="server" />
```

and javascript code is :

```
    <script>
var tmp = document.createElement("input");
tmp.appendChild(document.getElementById('txt_newpl'));

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: 
       '<div>'+tmp.innerHTML+'</div>'
    })
});

document.getElementById("<%= txt_place_name.ClientID%>").value = txt_java.value;
</script>
```

I want to transfer the value of the txt_newpl to the txt_place_name.
What is my wrong?

Comment: I think your question should be renamed, instead of 'get value of DOM element in code behind' should be something like "How to exchange value between an input and and asp:textbox controler'

Comment: Please try to format and empathise your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong. You **create an element input** and then **append your textbox** to it, after that you try to get **value of element input** (`txt_java.value`), which is wrong, you want **value of textbox** (`document.getElementById('txt_newpl').value`).

```
<script>
    // .. rest of the code ...
    document.getElementById("<%= txt_place_name.ClientID%>").value = document.getElementById('txt_newpl').value;
</script>
```

Also, wouldn't be easy if you add your `<asp:TextBox ... />` to the info window to be completed, like this. In this way you won't complicate your code with unnecessary exchange of values.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_place_name" CssClass="form-control ltr" ValidationGroup="add" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script>
    var tmp = document.createElement("input");
    tmp.appendChild(document.getElementById("<%= txt_place_name.ClientID %>"));

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:
            '<div>' + tmp.innerHTML + '</div>'
        })
    });
</script>
```

You can do this because `<asp:TextBox .../>` control will be rendered to an html element `<input type="text" ... />`. This render (transforming) process is happening on **sever side**.

Comment: i think info windows has problem with tmp.appendChild(document.getElementById("<%= txt_place_name.ClientID %>")); because when i use this line info windows not opening

Comment: @aliiii you tried to add attribute `ClientIDMode="Static"` in textbox and to use `tmp.appendChild(document.getElementById("txt_place_name"));`  ? Anyway, you tried my first option?

Comment: i did !!! 
this line is ok : tmp.appendChild(document.getElementById("txt_newpl"));
but this line is not working :
tmp.appendChild(document.getElementById("txt_place_name"));

Comment: excuse me :-) second method is true , my code has some extra codes that ruin this !!! thanks a lot adricadar