# Why does the method run without calling in script tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I write my project in Asp.net using JavaScript.My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     . . .
     var btnSaveInsert = document.getElementById("btnSaveInsert");
     . . .
     btnSaveInsert.onclick = function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var s = <%=Save() %>;
          modal2.style.display = "none";
          modal3.style.display = "block";
     }
```

This is my script tag.There are other functions too in script before this.
As you look, I call my Save method in button's click.

```
<input type="button" class="button-style" style="width:50px; height:30px; margin-left:50%;" id="btnInsertOK" value="OK"/>
```

And my Save() method in code behind:

```
protected string Save()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string json;
            string active = Request.Form["txtActive"];
            string code = Request.Form["txtCode"];
            string name = Request.Form["txtName"];
            string warehouse = Request.Form["txtWarehouse"];
            string url = "http://InsertData?active=" + active + "&code=" + code + "&name=" + name + "&warehouse=" + warehouse + "";

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                json = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
            string[] json1 = json.Split('>');
            string[] json2 = json1[2].Split('<');
            json = json2[0];

            return json;
        }
```

When the project start running firstly, Save() runs, and it inserts default string.How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You're not calling `Save()` in your method's button click event. You're populating the JavaScript code (in an attempt to populate `s`, I guess) with the result of `Save()` at the point in time when the page is rendered.

Comment: What use is `var s = <%=Save() %>;`? This is where it makes a call to `Save` method from code-behind.

Comment: **s** is bool variable. If insert is successfully it returns true. And I want to show message about this according to value of **s**.What do you think?How can I call `Save()`?

Comment: Similar links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725992/call-c-sharp-function-from-javascript-onclick-event-button   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646162/how-to-fire-a-button-click-event-from-javascript-in-asp-net

Comment: I would suggest reading up on asp.net server controls. Create the save button with `<asp:button id="save" runat="server">Save</asp:button>` and make sure you have an eventhandler that will be invoked when you click on save, in which you call `Save` method that you have written.

Comment: The `<%=Save() %>` runs on the server, *then* the text is sent to the browser where it is treated as javascript. The `<% %>` is gone by then. You probably want to investigate "ajax"